# Removing notification from a drawer after the sound is played and ticker displayed

Tags: android

I want to remove a notification from the drawer after it's being displayed as a ticker and after the sound is played (and vibration too).

I have the following code in my app

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_calendar_themedark)
            .setLights(0xffffffff, 500, 1000)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(context.getString(R.string.tewstgfd));

    if (vibratePattern != null) {
        mBuilder.setVibrate(vibratePattern);
    }

    if (soundUri != null) {
        mBuilder.setSound(soundUri, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
    }

    addPriorityHigh(mBuilder);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(R.string.e_notif_rest_id, mBuilder.build());
    mNotificationManager.cancel(R.string.e_notif_rest_id);
```

Notice the last 2 lines: I create notification and immediately remove it. However, this also stops notification sound and stops vibration. So only a ticker gets displayed, but this is not what I want at all. If I remove the last line (mNotificationManager.cancel(R.string.e_notif_rest_id), then notification stays in the drawer, but this is what I want to avoid.

What am I missing?

Comment: Simply waiting before you cancel the notification, as forgivegod suggests, would work of course. But I think this creates a very bad user experience and shouldn't be done.  Use a toast notification if you don't have reason to create (and keep) a full notification.

Comment: Darshan, Yes, this is exactly what I have now. I just wanted to replace 1) wake lock (for screen blinking), 2) music player (for sound) and 3) Vibration service (for vibrating) with one simple notification that basically can do all of this. BUt it seems that I cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try delaying the `.cancel`

```
final  NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
.....rest of your code...


/// might need to do this part in a background thread -- start
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

AssetFileDescriptor d = context.getAssets().openFd(fileName);
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(d.getFileDescriptor(), d.getStartOffset(), d.getLength());
mp.prepare();  
int duration = mp.getDuration();
mp.reset();
/// might need to do this part in a background thread -- end


mNotificationManager.notify(R.string.e_notif_rest_id, mBuilder.build());
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         mNotificationManager.cancel(R.string.e_notif_rest_id);
    }
}, duration+200 /*+ 200ms*/);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that you can cancel this, but it's not clear how long should it be there. In your example you have specified 30 seconds, but this can be a shorter time, it depends on duration of notification sound, which is hard to estimate.

Comment: Getting the length of time of a sound file is pretty easy (See edit).